# Checkboxes filter search result

Tags: php, jquery, filtering, checkbox

I need to filter my result like this:

http://www.babycarers.com/search?searchref=12935259587085&specreq=all&postcode=Postcode%2FZip+%28optional%29&country=CA&searchbutton.x=38&searchbutton.y=12

I know I have to use jQuery with Ajax. I have found some examples like this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/d2v4Q/

I don't want to play with the visibility. I would like to do the filtering and parsing of the user's selection using a PHP script.

Comment: Have you written any code yet?  If so, are you having any errors?  Adding this information to your question would be helpful in providing assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact architecture of your database, but what you'll want to do is use

http://api.jquery.com/change/

to detect a change in selection of a checkbox, then use

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

and pass all the parameters to a separate .php file to get the result off another page and print it out

So, an example.

```
<select class="order">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="date_poster">Date Posted</option>
</select>

<div id="results">
</div>

<script>
    $("select.order").change(function(){
        var orderBy = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "your_external_file.php",
          data: "orderBy="+orderBy,
          success: function(html){
            $("#results").append(html);
            //Add whatever you want to do here.
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Although I haven't tested it, it should work as long as you name the files correctly

Comment: I have an issue of passing the value to my "select" ..which I want to be independed on what the user has choose

Comment: Thank you this helps! I have checkboxes which have to change the search result as the user select them. I supposed I have to done this work in the myfile.php. You can see that http://www.babycarers.com/search?searchref=12935259587085&specreq=all&postcode=Postcode%2FZip+%28optional%29&country=CA&searchbutton.x=38&searchbutton.y=12 It use ajax loading script and jquery, thank you again

Comment: Do you know how can I pass the selected values from the checkboxes to my select query which is in myfile.php?